# GWT compiling java to javascript and time format

Tags: gwt

in Java I set the date as time in mSec since 1970, e.g.   futuredate=1640995200000l //1 Jan 2022.
When this is compiled into JavaScript by GWT, I believe it uses the Jsdate library which says it is a native javascript date object
1 jan 2022 ends up as this object in the JavaScript _.futuredate={l:3120128, m:391243, h:0}
Can someone help me interpret this format please, it doesn't quite make sense to me
thanks

Answer (score 1):

To work with date and time on the GWT client side one can use com.google.gwt.i18n.shared.**DateTimeFormat**. com.google.gwt.i18n.shared.**DateTimeFormat.PredefinedFormat** includes already many predefined formats, but you can naturally use your own, such as "EEEE, y MMMM dd".

Based on your example:

```
Date myDate = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").parse("01.01.2022");
DateTimeFormat myFormat = DateTimeFormat.getFormat(PredefinedFormat.ISO_8601);
String s = myFormat.format(myDate);
```

The first line only simulates the date that you already set in Java and it is meant to show another example of a date format and how to parse a String.